# Trouble with a playerhealth function

Tags: python

So I'm making a little python game in class.

Anyways, I have this as a function:

```
def checkplayerhealth (playerhealth):
    while playerhealth < 1000:
        if playerhealth < 0:
            input ("Looks like you died.  Better luck next time! Press any key to exit")
            sys.exit()
```

Whenever I call it, the game stops. Obviously this is because I need to find a way to run the loop, or at least be constantly checking playerhealth and let the rest of the game continue running.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I think you should change `while playerhealth < 1000:` to `if playerhealth < 1000:`, or just remove that line. It creates an infinite loop, because the condition never changes within the loop. What did you hope it would do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statements

```
while playerhealth < 1000:
    if playerhealth < 0:
```

will put you in an infinite loop if the function was called with anything greater than or equal to 0 and less than 1000. If you want to break that loop, you need code that changes the value of `playerhealth` in the loop to something that is less than 0 or equal to or greater than 1000.

Perhaps, you meant the function to be:

```
def checkplayerhealth (playerhealth):
    if playerhealth < 0:
        input ("Looks like you died.  Better luck next time! Press any key to exit")
        sys.exit()
```

Comment: In the context of the game, it seems like the loop isn't really needed at all. The logic seems to be "if health is less than 0, exit, otherwise continue", so it's probably not about "fixing" the while loop but removing it entirely.

Comment: Wow, I understand now.  I should just call the function whenever I have an event that takes away playerhealth.  I can't believe i didn't get that right away.  Thanks for your help, and Marius.